# How do you add more space for group stats in Scabard

Tags: tools, scabard

So, I've started using the [Scabard Campaign Management](http://www.scabard.com/) stuff, and it looks really cool.  Unfortunately I'm [having trouble entering nations as groups](http://www.scabard.com/campaign/32928/group/32930).  The problem is that the stat page for groups has space for 16 stats in two brackets by default, and I need significantly more to keep track of both laws and economics, which I'd like to do somewhere other than the big 'description' box on the group's front page.  Is there a way to add more boxes to the stat page, like you can on the connections page?  Should I be doing this somewhere else in the software?  Should I enter nations as something other than groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for GM's to add more cells to the Stats tab, regardless of whether it is a Character, Event, Group, Place or Item.  Though you'd prefer not to use the description for stats, many GM's do exactly that, as in the following example: [Carrinac in the Gyristan Campaign](http://www.scabard.com/campaign/27129/place/29882).

To make it look nicer, descriptions on Scabard can take a [limited set of HTML tags](http://www.scabard.com/page/HTML_Markup).

The Stats tab and the description are the only places I've seen GM's enter stats on Scabard.  There really is no other place to do it.

Nations are generally typed as Places. Unfortunately there is bug in which Places don't have *any* cells for stats.  But since your page is more about the people of a region, then Group is more appropriate.

*Full Disclosure: I am the developer of Scabard.  I just created two tasks: one is to fix Places to have stats; the other is to allow GM's to add more stats blocks.  Not sure when I can get to them since I'm in the middle of a big upgrade right now.*